# Sutta reference or teachings about Sleep timings?

Tags: personal-practice

In a Vipassana retreat you are made to wake up at 4 am, also similar is the case in the Zen retreat.

I have read numerous articles on advantage on waking up early.

Are there any Sutta references or teachings of Monks or Lama or Zen master which give advise on waking up early and going to bed early?

Answer (score 3):

Sutta Pitaka Vol 4 : Sutta. Ma. Mū. [Mahāassapurasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=12&A=8507&w=%BB%D1%A8%A9%D4%C1%C2%D2%C1&eng=suttacentral):

> What more is there to do?
>
> You should train yourselves like this: ‘We will be committed to
>   wakefulness.
>
> 1. When practicing walking and sitting meditation by day, we will
>      purifying our mind from obstacles.
> 2. In the evening, we will continue to practice walking and sitting
>      meditation.
> 3. In the middle of the night, we will lie down in the lion’s
>      posture—on the right side, placing one foot on top of the
>      other—mindful and aware, and focused on the time of getting up.
> 4. In the last part of the night, we will get up and continue to
>      practice walking and sitting meditation, purifying our mind from
>      obstacles.’
>
> Now, mendicants, you might think: ‘We have conscience and prudence,
>   our bodily, verbal, and mental behavior is pure, our livelihood is
>   pure, our sense doors are restrained, we don’t eat too much, and we
>   are committed to wakefulness. Just this much is enough …’